Flutter IOS app sending data to graphql server with single quotes

I have to send the query in the attached image to Shopify Graphql server in double quotes (I mean double quotes at the beginning and end. All other quotes need to be single quotes). But IOS Emulator is sending the data with single quotes(' ') which fetches no data.

Please share you code where you are making the API request..
